# Create Mutiple Level Menu from the ARRAY from the Database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Below are 2 functions that will handle the Query and rending of the menu from MySQL Database.

**This function Loops through the array. Takes in 2 arguments.**

```
function loop_section($array, $parent_id = 0){
        echo '<ul>';
            foreach($array as $section){
                echo '<li>';
                echo $section->section_name;
                echo '</li>';
            }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
```

**This function handles the Querying of the menu from the table section in the database.**

```
function fetch_sections(){
        global $db;
        $array = array();
        $query = $db->SELECT("SELECT * FROM sections");
        $array = $db->ROWS();
        loop_section($array);
    }
```

Here's my question, How will I use the array passed in loop_section() function to make multiple level menu?

Here is the database structure
[Database Strucutre](http://s27.postimg.org/hzlmpv6k3/sections.png)

Comment: you need to have a column for the order. That keeps track of the order of the menu. another column called parent_id which specifies what's the parent of the menu item.

Comment: I already have those. Please see the edited question (Database structure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but try something like this:

```
function print_section(array $sections, $parent_id = null) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($sections as $section) {
        if($section->parent_id != $parent_id)
            continue;
        echo '<li>';
        echo $section->section_name;
        print_section($sections, $section->section_id);
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

function fetch_sections(){
    global $db;
    $query = $db->SELECT("SELECT * FROM sections ORDER BY section_order"); // assuming that you have section_order column
    return $db->ROWS();
}

function print_sections() {
    print_section(fetch_sections());
}
```

Comment: This works great, just to tweak abit to match my requirements. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$array_parent_id = array();

function fetch_sections($parent_id = null){
            global $db;
            $array = array();                       
            if($parent_id){
                    $query = $db->SELECT("SELECT * FROM sections where parent_id =".$parent_id);
                    $array_parent_id[] = $parent_id;            
            }else{
                $query = $db->SELECT("SELECT * FROM sections");

            }

                $array = $db->ROWS();
            loop_section($array);

        }

function loop_section($array, $parent_id = null){
            echo '<ul>';
                foreach($array as $section){
                                // check if parent_id of section into array $array_parent_id to pervent duplication             
                    if(in_array($section->parent_id,$array_parent_id)) continue;
                    echo '<li>';
                    echo $section->section_name;
                    if($section->parent_id != null){
                        fetch_sections($section->parent_id);                
                    }
                    echo '</li>';
                }
            echo '</ul>';
}
```